# TextMobject doesn't work on Jupyter-Manim

Tags: manim

I am currently using jupyter-manim since it is the most efficient way for me to use manim. I'm running my code on Kaggle and every time I use TextMobject in manim, it outputs an error that says `Latex error converting to dvi. See log output above or the log file: media/Tex/54dfbfee288272f0.log`. I've tried TexMobject and Text function, but only the Text function works. The Text function is limited however, and I'm not sure how to change the font. Is there a way to fix this or is it something that comes with using jupyter-manim? It seems that all the other functions work such as drawing shapes, animating scenes, etc.

```
%%manim
class Text(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        first_line = TextMobject('Hi')
        second_line = TexMobject('Hi')
        #Only one that works
        third_line = Text('Hi')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your Manim program and it worked as expected for me. I would try making sure

1. include `from manimlib.imports import *` in your first line (importing Manim library)
2. include self.play(...) so you can see them

I think you already have these, but I'm putting them in case you don't.

You may also be getting the error because you do not have a LaTeX distribution installed on your system (i.e. MikTex or Texlive).

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem may be the name of the class you chose.  I had problems with your code until I changed the name from `Text` to `TextTest`.  Here is a minimally working example that works fine in my Jupyter notebook (after running `import jupyter_manim` of course).

```
%%manim TextTest -p -ql

from manim import *

class TextTest(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        first_line = TextMobject('Hi 1')
        second_line = TexMobject('Hi 2').shift(DOWN)
        third_line = Text('Hi 3').shift(UP)
        self.add(first_line)
        self.add(second_line)
        self.add(third_line)
        self.wait(1)
```

Also, you should be aware that `TextMobject` and `TexMobject` have been deprecated.